# How to stop async function in c# unity?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, async-await

One more question. I found a cancellationToken in the unit that makes a cancellationRequest when leaving the playmod.
I implemented it in my fade in/out system, which has:

1. smoothly change the material color of the objects to be faded in/out
2. change the frame (texture)
3. smoothly change the color back

Part of code 1 an abstract class from which all such objects are inherited.
when calling `ChangeCurrentByDayTime`, the manipulations described above should begin.
Part of code 2 - one of the child objects (in the screenshots it is always the same), implementation of the `ChangeTextureByDayTime` method
when calling `ChangeTextureByDayTime`, the RawImage frame (texture) itself should change
Part of code 3 - logic of `FadeIn` in the child object
when exiting the playmod, by checking in the `FadeIn` method whether there was a sudden request cancellation, the logic must stop the asynchronous method.

1

```
public abstract class Fadeable : MonoBehaviour
{  
    public virtual async void ChangeCurrentByDayTime(DayTime dayTime, CancellationToken token)
    {
        await FadeIn(token);

        ChangeTextureByDayTime(dayTime);
        
        await FadeOut(token);
    }
    public abstract Task FadeIn(CancellationToken token);
    public abstract Task FadeOut(CancellationToken token);
    public abstract void ChangeTextureByDayTime(DayTime dayTime);
}
```

2

```
// _rend - RawImage
    private void ChangeBGTexture(Texture2D texture)
    {
        if (_rend.isActiveAndEnabled) 
        {
            _rend.material.mainTexture = texture;
            _rend.texture = texture;
        }
    }
```

3

```
public override async Task FadeOut(CancellationToken token) 
    {
        float currentChangeTime = 0;
        while (currentChangeTime <= _changeToDayTime)
        {           
            _rend.material.color = Color.Lerp(_color2, _color1, currentChangeTime/_changeToDayTime);
            currentChangeTime += Time.deltaTime;
            await Task.Yield();
            if (token != null && token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Debug.Log("FadeOut has been ended!");
                return;
            }
        }
        Debug.Log("FadeOut has been ended!");
    }
```

Question: How can I make the FadeIn/FadeOut methods stop the `ChangeCurrentByDayTime` method from inside in general, or how can I make this method stop itself when `cancellationRequest` from `Application.exitCancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested`?

What I tried:

- async methods can't have out and ref as arguments, so you can't return a bool.
- FadeIn and FadeOut are virtual, because you can't make an abstract async method in the body of an abstract class

Comment: You might also want to read https://hackernoon.com/the-complete-asynchronous-programming-primer-for-unity-development

Comment: You can't really if you don't pass along the cancellation token also into that one I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most *natural* way of implementing this is to use cancellation the way it was designed: by throwing `OperationCanceledException` instead of just returning early:

```
public virtual async Task ChangeCurrentByDayTime(DayTime dayTime, CancellationToken token)
{
  try
  {
    await FadeIn(token);
    ChangeTextureByDayTime(dayTime);
    await FadeOut(token);
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException)
  {
    Debug.Log("Cancelled!");
  }
}

public override async Task FadeOut(CancellationToken token) 
{
  float currentChangeTime = 0;
  while (currentChangeTime <= _changeToDayTime)
  {           
    _rend.material.color = Color.Lerp(_color2, _color1, currentChangeTime/_changeToDayTime);
    currentChangeTime += Time.deltaTime;
    await Task.Yield();
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  }
  Debug.Log("FadeOut has been ended!");
}
```

However, if you want to avoid exceptions, then you can implement a non-standard cancellation pattern by returning a `bool`:

```
public virtual async Task ChangeCurrentByDayTime(DayTime dayTime, CancellationToken token)
{
  if (!await FadeIn(token))
    return;
  ChangeTextureByDayTime(dayTime);
  if (!await FadeOut(token))
    return;
}

public override async Task<bool> FadeOut(CancellationToken token) 
{
  float currentChangeTime = 0;
  while (currentChangeTime <= _changeToDayTime)
  {           
    _rend.material.color = Color.Lerp(_color2, _color1, currentChangeTime/_changeToDayTime);
    currentChangeTime += Time.deltaTime;
    await Task.Yield();
    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
      Debug.Log("FadeOut has been ended!");
      return false;
    }
  }
  Debug.Log("FadeOut has been ended!");
  return true;
}
```

Side note: I changed `ChangeCurrentByDayTime` from `async void` to `async Task`, since the `async void` there is almost certainly a bug.